# Eclipse - build and run with different java versions

Tags: java, spring

I would like to build a project with one version of java (8) and run it with another (jdk17), I don't find where to put the jdk17 on execution only (as the java build path setting will take both build and run) .

Any help ?

Thanks

Comment: A Java project compiled to the Java 8 standard should run on any higher Java JDK.

Answer (score 0):

Run > Run Configuration > Java Application > JRE tab should let you speify what JRE(or JDK) to run java with in eclipse.

Right clicking your project and going to Properties > Java Build Path > Libraries lets you specify what JRE system library you're using to build the project.

However I doubt a project built with Java 8 will run on Java 17.

Comment: Thanks, that is what I've done but I have an error at runtime:
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "Object.getClass()" because "obj" is null

                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:561) ~[?:?]

                at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:333) ~[spring-aop-4.3.25.RELEASE.jar:4.3.25.RELEASE]

I had the exact same error when building and running with jdk17